# Maximal ideals of polynomial ring $\mathbb Z_n[x]$

Tags: ring-theory

How would I find one? say $n=p^2q^2$ for $p,q$ primes

Comment: Do you know what the maximal ideals of $\mathbf Z[x]$ look like?

Comment: does it directly follow from that?

Comment: If you understand things well enough, then certainly. (I guess you don't if you had to ask.) You just need to figure out which maximal ideals in that ring contain your $n$. After all, the ring you write is isomorphic to $\mathbf Z[x]/(n)$, so you can use the description of maximal ideals in a quotient ring $R/I$  in terms of maximal ideals in $R$. But there can be other solutions that don't rely on knowing maximal ideals of $\mathbf Z[x]$.

Comment: so does it make sense to say $p \mathbb Z_n$ is a maximal? Is it anything?

Comment: Take the quotient by that and see if you get a field. That would tell you if it is maximal. For comparison, is $p\mathbf Z$ a maximal ideal in $\mathbf Z[x]$?